# How can I reset buttons back to default style if I have * {padding: 0; margin: 0;} set?

Tags: css

I have a page with

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

set and it's the only way I can get the layout to work properly across all the browsers, but it unfortunately also makes any buttons in forms looks really ugly. I want the browser default styling on the button.

Is there any kind of CSS I can put to fix it?

Comment: "Is there any kind of CSS I can put to fix it?" - how about styling the buttons to not make them look ugly? Just a thought :p

Comment: Also, look into using styled divs instead of browser widgets, as they are a lot more cross browser/os friendly.

Comment: @danp: I wouldn't recommend styled divs to replace `<button>` because you lose a lot of the accessibility functions then. You can style `<button>` any way you like, though, and still get all the accessibility functionality for free.

Comment: True true, but the fact remains that the default browser widgets are pig ugly. I'll play with button elements a bit more though, thanks for tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to return to CSS back to the browser once you've specified a rule that overrides the browser style (never seen one in all my years, anyway).

I think, rather than a blanket reset like what you have there, you might want to try using a more sophisticated reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Of course, you can further adapt either of these - but they are pretty solid foundations for CSS.

Answer (score 3):

> it's the only way I can get the layout to work properly across all the browsers

I would suggest you fix that problem, rather then trying to just override it for buttons. Having said that, you can just explicitly put the padding back in:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=button], button {
    padding: 6px;
}
```

(I don't know if "6px" is the default, but you can experiment).

Additionally, instead of just setting * with "padding: 0" you could try one of the [reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) files which set it up on just those elements that require it.

Comment: I agree -- the reset CSS files do a better job than * {}. They'll give you decent, consistent styles across browsers. Here's Yahoo's: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/

Comment: input[type=button] will not work in IE6 and IE7 - and probably not in IE8 (haven't really tried just that in IE8 since I now use <input type="button" class="button" ... /> )

Comment: @HorusKol: That's a good point... in any case, I do think the reset CSS files are better...